# Set httpd-root as current work directory in init.el

Tags: init-file

I want to setup httpd-root variable as current emacs work directory in init.el. So I added below line in init.el.

```
(setq httpd-root default-directory)
```

This line works fine in linux, but in windows, it point to my home directory. I just add emacs.exe path in system variable, then go to specific directory from powershell, input emacs to launch emacs UI.

My expected behavior is when I launch emacs in one directory,say d:\exam, that variable should point to it (d:\exam).

Comment: How (specificly) are you launching Emacs on your Windows machine for purposes of this particular thread/question, and please specify how it is that you are lunching it from a certain directory such as `d:\exam`?  For example, are you launching a GUI version of Emacs from the terminal by first `cd`-ing over to the `d:\exam` directory` and then launching `.../path/to/emacs.exe`?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: I just add emacs.exe path to system path variable, then go to specific directory to launch the emacs UI.